# OpenLayers fit to extent doesn't work

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

I have the following example:

```
<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<div id="mapdiv"></div>
  
<script>
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
    
    
    var ll1 = new OpenLayers.LonLat( -122.258933 , 37.858088 )
          .transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            map.getProjectionObject()
          );
    var ll2 = new OpenLayers.LonLat( -122.291882 , 37.831349 )
          .transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            map.getProjectionObject()
          );

    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
    map.addLayer(markers);

    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(ll1));
    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(ll2));

    map.getView().fit(markers.getDataExtent());
</script>
```

I am able to obtain valid values from markers.getDataExtent(), however the map never get zoomed to the extend somehow. I did able to manually set a zoom level and zoom to one of the points, but that's not usable for my case. Any suggestion?

Comment: Any special reason for using ages old and obsolete version 2 of OL?

Comment: Found examples based on the old code online. Translation to the newest code is highly appreciated!

Comment: That's up to you to find latest examples. Good start is official OL site: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/

Comment: most likely your map is in EPSG:3587 and your data extent is in EPSG:4326 so you end up looking at Null Island

Comment: You are mixing code from OpenLayers 2.x series with 3+ version. `map.getView().fit(markers.getDataExtent());` is OpenLayers 3+ snippet and the beginning is OpenLayers 2.x. It will never works this way